Question on the readiness of Karate framework for mobile app UI test
I would like to inquire on the readiness of karate framework for mobile app UI test (Appium)
https://karatelabs.github.io/karate/examples/mobile-test/
The website says "Please consider Mobile support as experimental. But we are very close and there are some teams that use Karate for simple use-cases. Please contribute code if you can."
What does it mean by "experimental"? (our dev/test team would like to see if this framework can be used on their mobile app projects)
If the framework is not quite ready, how soon it will be production ready? (feel free to provide rough estimation e.g., Q2 2025)
Any link to GIT repo for the example project that we can study from?
Thank you.
We would love to start using Karate Appium framework

Creator of Karate here, the status is still experimental and there is no ETA, sorry. Karate is open-source, you are welcome to evaluate it for your needs and contribute where there are gaps.

Thank you Peter! any link to existing GIT repo that we can use for mobile UI test?

I think what you found is the best reference
